# Is it possible to query MySQL to get only fields that contain duplicate/repeating strings?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I mean is, I have table with a "list" column. The data that goes into the "list" is related to addresses, so I sometimes get repeated zip codes for one record in that field.

For example, "12345,12345,12345,12456".

I want to know if it's possible to construct a query that would find the records that have an unknown string that duplicates within the field, such that I would get the records like "12345,12345,12345,12456", but not ones like "12345,45678,09876".

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you looking to return results for all rows that have a duplicate zip code? (Your example has 3 duplicates then another value of 12456 which is unclear)

Comment: Start by familiarising yourself with all the possible useful [MySQL string Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: If it is not too late, you may want to re-think your schema and not store lists as delimited strings, and instead store them in a separate table which makes tasks like this very simple - [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1048425)

Comment: Saving data like this its not best practice at all. save these sub lists in different table. Stored procedures can help you to receive the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use a numbers table to convert your delimited string into rows, then use group by to find duplicates, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, List VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO T (ID, List)
VALUES (1, '12345,12345,12345,12456'), (2, '12345,45678,09876');

SELECT
  T.ID,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.list, ',', n.Number), ',', -1) AS ListItem
FROM T
    INNER JOIN
    (   SELECT 1 AS Number UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5
    ) AS n 
        ON CHAR_LENGTH(T.list)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(T.list, ',', ''))>=n.Number-1
GROUP BY T.ID, ListItem
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you don't have a numbers table you can create one in a derived query as I have above with `UNION ALL`

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntxekfi9xbcKHvwfxC8819/0)**

With that being said, this is almost certainly not the right way to store your data, you should instead use a child table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE ListItems
(
      MainTableId INT NOT NULL, --Foreign Key to your current table
      ItemName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL -- Or whatever data type you need
);
```

Then your query is much more simple:

```
SELECT T.ID, li.ItemName
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN ListItems AS li
            ON li.MainTableId = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID, li.ItemName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you need to recreate your original format, this is easily done with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT T.ID, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(li.ItemName) AS List
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN ListItems AS li
            ON li.MainTableId = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID;
```

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntxekfi9xbcKHvwfxC8819/2)**

Answer (score -1):

I am still unclear what your desired result is based on your question however if it is simply to get all rows where there is a duplicate entry in column list you  could do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN IN
   (SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE 
   having count(*) >1)
```